# Hierarchical method of regression in R

Tags: r, regression

We are looking to use a "hierarchical" method of regression in order to input predictor variables in three steps. From what we can tell, the default method of regression is "stepwise," but we can't seem to find out how to fit a model hierarchically or with forced entry. Note that we are not trying to fit a Hierarchical Linear Model (HLM) / Multi-level Model (MLM), but are trying to change the method of regression to specify the order variables are entered into the model.

Specifically, we are trying to fit the following three models, with the two-way interactions in m2ai, and the three-way interaction in m3ai, being input as 2nd and 3rd steps, respectively:

```
m1ai <- lm(PostValUVAve ~ cPreValUVAve + Int + Gender + SciTeacher + cPreEff + cPreInt)
m2ai <- lm(PostValUVAve ~ cPreValUVAve + Int + Gender + SciTeacher + cPreEff + cPreInt +
                          cPreEff*Int + cPreInt*Int)
m3ai <- lm(PostValUVAve ~ cPreValUVAve + Int + Gender + SciTeacher + cPreEff + cPreInt +
                          cPreEff*Int + cPreInt*Int + cPreEff*Int*cPreInt)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use the same the main effects estimates for all the models? For that, you should use `offset()`.

Comment: Thanks. Possibly (not sure). Would that allow for the same two-way interaction estimates between the 2nd and 3rd models as well?

Comment: Yes, writing up a more thorough answer.

Comment: Are you just wondering how to get R to do this for you? Or are you wondering something about the nature of this procedure?

Comment: Especially how to get R to do this, but both would help us.

Comment: The `*` is a shorthand for main effects plus interactions, which are indicated by `:`, e.g. `cPreEff*Int = cPreEff + Int + cPreEff:Int`. That means you have multiple copies of `cPreEff`, etc. in your formula. I think R catches these, but I think you'll want to change your `*` to `:`.

Comment: How to do X in `R` is off-topic here (see our [help/on-topic]), but can be on-topic on [SO] w/ a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536). However, you've already done it, so it isn't clear what the issue is. You might be importing into R modeling strategies that are common in SPSS (I remember it lets you enter variables in blocks). If you want to do a series of nested model tests, you can use `anova(m2ai, m3ai)`, `anova(m1ai, m2ai0`.

Comment: Thanks for the help all. From what we understand, in hierarchical regression predictors are input as suggested by theory / some a priori decision, while in stepwise regression predictors the software picks and chooses. Is this a fundamentally rough understanding?

Comment: I really don't follow that, @JoshuaRosenberg. If you've decided a-priori to fit `m3ai`, then you've already done that (`m1ai` & `m2ai` are superfluous, though). Just go w/ the model you already decided on. I don't see anything to do here.

Comment: The term "hierarchical" in regression usually refers to something that I think is different to what you seem to be asking about (your question isn't sufficiently clear for me to be certain, though). If you're asking "how do I enter blocks of predictors in R?" that's straightforward (use `update` and specify the set of predictors) but for it to be on topic here the question would have to have a clearly statistical component (i.e. not simply be a request for R syntax).

Comment: We were asking how to enter blocks of predictors in R but it turns out we were thinking hierarchical meant something other than the process of using update() to specify the set of predictors. Essentially, comparing the models to compare the output of the model fit was missing. Thanks.

Comment: Ah. You use `anova` to compare the sequence of *nested* models. e.g. `mdl1 <- lm(y ~ x1)` then `mdl2 <- lm(y ~ x1+x2+x3)` then `anova(mdl1,mdl2)`. The `anova` function can take multiple such models and will put the results into a table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the default method is Forced Entry. Hierarchical Regression can be done manually as follows (I'm not sure if you are using "*" when you mean to use ":" for the interaction and I'm going to mention "I" as a modeling tool in R, so here's a *review*:

```
m1 <- lm(formula = outcome ~ predictor1, data = data) # copy and paste for the next line
m2 <- lm(formula = outcome ~ predictor1 + predictor2, data = data) # edited version of above line
m3 <- lm(formula = outcome ~ predictor1 + predictor2 + predictor1:predictor2, data = data) # added an interaction to the equation
anova(m1, m2, m3) # this compares the output of your model fit
```

You can also use the update() function as follows:

```
m1 <- lm(formula = outcome ~ predictor1, data = data) # same as above
m2 <- update(m1, . ~ . + predictor2)
m3 <- update(m2, . ~ . + predictor1:predictor2)
anova(m1, m2, m3)
```

**Now**, try this code and see if it gives you the output you're looking for.

```
m1ai <- lm(PostValUVAve ~ cPreValUVAve + Int + Gender + SciTeacher + cPreEff + cPreInt)
m2ai <- update(m1ai, . ~ . + cPreEff:Int + cPreInt:Int)
m3ai <- update(m2ai, . ~ . + + IcPreEff:Int:cPreInt)
anova(m1ai, m2ai, m3ai)
```

Comment: What does "I" do? m2ai and m3ai throw errors ("variable lengths differ"), although they do not when I omit "I".

Comment: I updated the example to remove the "I"'s